# Custom validation of forms with react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to figuring out how to add custom validation messages to my form

My code looks like this

```
 <Form noValidate validated={ validated } onSubmit={ onSubmit } style={ { 'width': '90%' } }>
    <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="company">                
       <Form.Label>Company</Form.Label>                             
       <Form.Control type="company"                                 
                  name="company"                                 
                  placeholder="Enter company name"               
                  // required                                    
                  minLength={5}                                  
                  value={ fields.company }                       
                  onChange={ onFieldChange }                     
    />                                                           
    <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">                        
        Please enter the company name.                           
    </Form.Control.Feedback>                                     
  </Form.Group>                                                    
</Form>
```

Note that I issue a generic message `Please enter the company name`, if there is any validation error.  But I want to have a different message if the field is blank versus the user enters something but it's not long enough, since the minimum length is 5.

I also have another situation where the user enters his email twice and I compare to make sure they are the same.

I've read about `setCustomValidity` but I can't figure out how to get out the message that it stores.  I'd tried some of the things that I've found online.  Ideally, I want to be able to have some logic like this:

```
<Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">                        
        if (missing) Please enter the company name. 
        if (tooshort) Name must be at least 5 characters                          
</Form.Control.Feedback>
```

or maybe like this

```
<Form.Control.Feedback type="missing">                        
    Please enter the company name.                         
</Form.Control.Feedback>  
<Form.Control.Feedback type="tooshort">                        
    Name must be at least 5 characters                          
</Form.Control.Feedback>
```

How can I make the error message more dynamic?

Comment: you can write function for that custom logic, and set message appropriate

Comment: I'm already setting the message using setCustomValidity, but I can't figure out how to get the message out at render time.